# How to show output in a JLabel after imputing operation in another textbox?

Tags: java, swing

I'm currently making a calculator where I input the operation in a textbox and to the right of it, there is a button. If I press enter in the textbox or press the button, the answer or an error message should show up in a JLabel underneath. I'm able to somewhat show the input textbox and button but don't know how to show answer once button is clicked or enter is pressed in label.

Viewer

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class CalculatorViewer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new CalculatorViewerFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setTitle("FontViewer");
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Frame

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class CalculatorViewerFrame extends JFrame {
       private JLabel resultLabel;
       private JTextField inputField;
       private JButton button;
       private ActionListener listener;

       private static final int FRAME_WIDTH = 500;
       private static final int FRAME_HEIGHT = 300;

       public CalculatorViewerFrame() {
           class Calculate implements ActionListener {
               public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                   String input = inputField.getText();
                   input = input.trim();
                   int x = 0,y=0;
                   String operator;
                   try {
                       x = Integer.parseInt(input.substring(0,input.indexOf(" ")));
                   } catch(InvalidExpressionException exception) {
                          resultLabel.setText("The first operand is not an integer");
                   }
                   if (input.indexOf(" ")==input.lastIndexOf(" ") || input.indexOf(" ")+1==input.lastIndexOf(" ")) {
                       operator = " ";
                   } else {
                       operator = input.substring(input.indexOf(" "), input.lastIndexOf(" "));
                   }
                   operator = operator.trim();
                   try {
                       y= Integer.parseInt(input.substring(input.lastIndexOf(" ")));
                   } catch(InvalidExpressionException exception) {
                       resultLabel.setText("The second operand is not an integer");
                   }
                   int answer;
                   String operation = x +" " + operator + y+ " = ";
                   switch (operator) {
                    case "+": answer = x + y;
                    resultLabel.setText(operation + answer);
                    resultLabel.repaint();
                    case "-": answer = x - y;
                    resultLabel.setText(operation + answer);
                    resultLabel.repaint();
                    case "*": answer = x * y;
                    switch (y) {
                    case 0: resultLabel.setText("Cannot divide by 0");
                    }
                    resultLabel.setText(operation + answer);
                    resultLabel.repaint();
                    case "/": answer = x / y;
                    resultLabel.setText(operation + answer);
                    resultLabel.repaint();
                    case "%": answer = x % y;
                    resultLabel.setText(operation + answer);
                    resultLabel.repaint();
                    default: resultLabel.setText("Illegal operator");
                   }
               }
           }

           createInputPanel();
           resultLabel = new JLabel();
           add(resultLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
           listener = new Calculate();

           setSize(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);
       }


       public void createInputPanel() {
           JPanel inputPanel = createInputTextField();
           JPanel compute = createButton();

           JPanel controlPanel = new JPanel();
           controlPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));
           controlPanel.add(inputPanel);
           controlPanel.add(compute);

           add(controlPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
       }

       private JPanel createInputTextField() {
           inputField = new JTextField(20);
           inputField.setEditable(true);
           inputField.requestFocus();
           inputField.setText("");
           JPanel panel = new JPanel();
           inputField.addActionListener(listener);
           panel.add(inputField);
           return panel;
       }

       public JPanel createButton() {
           button = new JButton("Compute");
           JPanel panel = new JPanel();
           button.addActionListener(listener);
           panel.add(button);
           return panel;
       }
}
```

Here are pictures of what it should look like/similar to.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: What exactly is the question? What does not work? Are you having trouble setting text in the output? Doesn't the calculator not compute?

Comment: You've defined Calculate as a class.  A class can have more than one method.  You have way too much code in the actionPerformed method to debug properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I super agree with Scheintod to his feedback. I will leave that to him as he nailed it. I managed to optimize your code. See my comments inside the code and learn from it. I think this is your homework/project, is it? Lol.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class CalculatorViewerFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener { // you dont need to create sub class and
                                                                                // implement ActionListener to it. You
                                                                                // can do it here
    private JLabel resultLabel;
    private JTextField inputField;
    private JButton button;

    private static final int FRAME_WIDTH = 500;
    private static final int FRAME_HEIGHT = 300;

    public CalculatorViewerFrame() {
        createInputPanel();
        resultLabel = new JLabel();
        add(resultLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        setSize(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);
    }

    private void createInputPanel() { // set your modifier into private, it is not used from other class
        JPanel inputPanel = createInputTextField();
        JPanel compute = createButton();

        JPanel controlPanel = new JPanel();
        controlPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 2));
        controlPanel.add(inputPanel);
        controlPanel.add(compute);

        add(controlPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    }

    private JPanel createInputTextField() {
        inputField = new JTextField(20);
        inputField.setEditable(true);
        inputField.requestFocus();
        inputField.setText("");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        inputField.addActionListener(this); // since you implemented it to this class. you can use `this` as your input in parameter addActionListener
        panel.add(inputField);
        return panel;
    }

    private JPanel createButton() { // set your modifier into private, it is not used from other class
        button = new JButton("Compute");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        button.addActionListener(this); // same thing with line 50
        panel.add(button);
        return panel;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Compute")) { // though you have only one action. always check for this as it
                                                        // tells what action event happened.
            // parse and validate
            String input = inputField.getText();
            input = input.trim();
            int x = 0, y = 0;
            String operator;

            try {
                x = Integer.parseInt(input.substring(0, input.indexOf(" ")).trim());
            } catch (NumberFormatException exception) { // check your catch exception too. Remove that is/are not relevant to your try block
                resultLabel.setText("The first operand is not an integer");
                return; // you need to stop the process from here. you are using resultLabel all the time and you setText into it.
            }

            if (input.indexOf(" ") == input.lastIndexOf(" ") || input.indexOf(" ") + 1 == input.lastIndexOf(" ")) {
                operator = " ";
            } else {
                operator = input.substring(input.indexOf(" "), input.lastIndexOf(" "));
            }
            operator = operator.trim();

            try {
                y = Integer.parseInt(input.substring(input.lastIndexOf(" ")).trim()); // trim for white spaces.
            } catch (NumberFormatException exception) {
                resultLabel.setText("The second operand is not an integer");
                return; // you need to stop the process from here. you are using resultLabel all the time and you setText into it.
            }

            compute(x, y, operator);
        }
    }

    private void compute(int x, int y, String operator) { // you can move this block of code into another method as it
                                                            // is a new process.
        int answer;
        String operation = x + " " + operator + y + " = ";
        switch (operator) {
        case "+":
            answer = x + y;
            resultLabel.setText(operation + answer);
            resultLabel.repaint();
            break; // use break as it the process will continue. your case would be useless then.
        case "-":
            answer = x - y;
            resultLabel.setText(operation + answer);
            resultLabel.repaint();
            break;
        case "*":
            answer = x * y; // you dont need to spam switch condition. 
                            // if you are checking for one condition, use IF
            if (y == 0) {
                resultLabel.setText("Cannot divide by 0");
            }
            resultLabel.setText(operation + answer);
            resultLabel.repaint();
            break;
        case "/":
            answer = x / y;
            resultLabel.setText(operation + answer);
            resultLabel.repaint();
            break;
        case "%":
            answer = x % y;
            resultLabel.setText(operation + answer);
            resultLabel.repaint();
            break;
        default:
            resultLabel.setText("Illegal operator");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

To answer your question, how to show output. You need to use return in the method actionPerformed when it fell in catch block. Because you need to terminate the process.

Try to look this.
When the error comes up, you set text to resultLabel. Saying "The operand is not an integer".

Then computation proceeds and you set a text again in resultLabel. What would be the value in resultLabel?

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks Jhaytootz Torres, you were right about this being homework. Thank you for putting what Scheintod into code. This helped me understand a bit more of what Scheintod was refering to. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

First of all: Please clean up your code before asking questions on StackOverflow. This serves two main reasons:

- cleaner code is more easily understood by yourself. In most cases after cleaning up the problem is obvious and you even don't have to ask.
- second: everyone reading your question has to do it to understand it. Now you have 20 people potentially trying to help and everyone of them has to do it. This scales badly.

Now to your problem: Since you don't wrote what it is you are having trouble with I'm guessing that you don't get the button pressed event.

The reason for that is, that you instantiate your `listener = new Calculator()` after creating your fields/panels. But you use it in creating them here: `inputField.addActionListener(listener);` where `listener` is still `null`. So try moving it some lines to the top and you get your event.

(This would be obvious with cleaner code, did I mention?)

There are more problems in this code but with this change you will get at least some error messages when clicking the button so I will leave you with that.

Comment: Sorry if my code isn't clear, this is the first time i'm making an GUI. As Jhaytootz Torres guessed correct, this is a homework for school. My teacher taught us the methods and gave us slides to work off but in terms of implementing the code, she wasn't clear in show the answer after i click on the button. Thank you for the help Scheintod.

Comment: You're welcome. If you find yourself not understanding what your code is doing it's nearly always a good idea to rewrite it in a way that you understand it again. And then most of the problems are obvious. And try not using side-effects which in your case means write functions in a way that they only return a value and not change anything else. Or maybe just change a value and return nothing. But try not to mix. But this is where the art starts and books are written...